# Postgres: remove second occurrence of a string

Tags: regex, postgresql, replace

I tried to fix bad data in postgres DB where photo tags are appended twice.

`The trip is wonderful.<photo=2-1-1601981-7-1.jpg><photo=2-1-1601981-5-2.jpg>We enjoyed it very much.<photo=2-1-1601981-5-2.jpg><photo=2-1-1601981-7-1.jpg>`

As you can see in the string, photo tags  were added already, but they were appended to the text again. I want to remove the second occurrence: . The first occurrence has certain order and I want to keep them.

I wrote a function that could construct a regex pattern:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dd_trip_photo_tags(tagId int) RETURNS text 
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE  
AS $$
SELECT string_agg(concat('<photo=',media_name,'>.*?(<photo=',media_name,'>)'),'|')  FROM   t_ddtrip_media WHERE tag_id=tagId $$;
```

This captures the second occurrence of a certain photo tag.
Then, I use regex_replace to replace the second occurrence:
update t_ddtrip_content set content =  regexp_replace(content,dd_trip_photo_tags(332761),'') from t_ddtrip_content where tag_id=332761;

Yet, it would remove all matched tags. I looked up online for days but still couldn't figure out a way to fix this. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

This Should Work.

Regex 1:

```
<photo=.+?>
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/thHmlq/1

Regex 2:

```
<.+?>
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/thHmlq/2

Input:

```
The trip is wonderful.<photo=2-1-1601981-7-1.jpg><photo=2-1-1601981-5-2.jpg>We enjoyed it very much.<photo=2-1-1601981-5-2.jpg><photo=2-1-1601981-7-1.jpg>
```

Output:

```
<photo=2-1-1601981-7-1.jpg>
<photo=2-1-1601981-5-2.jpg>
<photo=2-1-1601981-5-2.jpg>
<photo=2-1-1601981-7-1.jpg>
```